# How to place UI elements to the position we want in Android?

Tags: android

I have some buttons, textboxes etc. in my android application, but when i drag them with my mouse in the xml file, their place doesn't change, or changes but they are not placed where i exactly wanted. How can i adjust their positions in the screen?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly there is no such thing as absolute positionning in android ( RIP `AbsoluteLayout` deprecated since years.)

instead you have to position views according to their parents and according to other views in the same parent.

first you have to define wich parent you need ( if you want some viens in a single line go for a `LinearLayout`. a more custom layout: use a `RelativeLayout` ...)

then you can drag and drop views inside, but they will always snap a position relative to their parent and/or relative to the other views.

you can of course play with margins.

A list of layout type with some advanced techniques can be found on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You RelativeLayout as a group layout for your layout so positioning can somewhat easy using mouse.

Best is to arrange them from the xml code. Just Learn about using the Relative layout, LinearLayout and TableLayout

Answer (score 0):

Learn how the XML works.  For a LinearLayout, the items come in the order listed.  For a RelativeLayout, the items are related by the values of their layout_XXX properties.  Then you don't have to worry about the WYSIWYG tool not working.

FYI, the tool bundled with eclipse is extremely buggy.  Don't count on whats on there being what's on your phone for anything non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others wrote it is easier to edit layout using xml editor. You can read more here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html.